# Проверка переменной на null

Tags: c++, null

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;
float a, b, h;
ofstream ofile;
float f(float x){
    try{
        return log(sqrt(3.0*x-1.0))/x/cos(x+2.0);
    }
    catch(...){
        return NULL;
    }
}
void print(){
    ofile.open("out.txt", ios_base::out);
    ll cnt=0;
    cout << "Undefined x:\n";
    for(float i=a; i<=b; i+=h){
        float y=f(i);
        if(y==NULL) cout << i << '\n';
        ofile << i << " " << y << "\n";
        ++cnt;
    }
    cout << "\nDots number - " << cnt << "\n";
    ofile.close();
}
int main(){
    cin >> a >> b >> h;
    print();
    return 0;
}
```

При выполнении программы не выполняется условие y==NULL, хотя должно. В чём проблема?

Comment: Проблема в непонимании, как работают исключения и чем они ограничены...

Comment: в данном случае исключения работают правильно. я посмотрел в отладчике, что возвращает функция при x не в области определения - как раз нужное значение nan. Но как проверить, что переменная равна этому значению, я не знаю

Comment: `NaN` — это не исключение, а [специальное значение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE), которое могут иметь типы с плавающей точкой формата  IEEE 754. Проверить на `NaN` можно с помощью функции [`std::isnan`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan).

Comment: @wololo Формально может быть не только NaN, но и бесконечность, например... Inho, лучше сразу все ловить через `isnormal()`.

Comment: @Harry, если нужно ловить ещё и бесконечность, то лучше [`std::isfinite`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isfinite), т.к. `std::isnormal` возвращает `false` для нуля. Хотя, конечно, если ноль тоже нужно отбрасывать, то лучше `std::isnormal`.

Comment: Переменные типа float вообще нельзя сравнивать операторами == и !=. Компилятор об этом не догадывается, не его дело заботиться о допусках, но программист-то должен это знать. И что за суперхитрость число с налом сравнивать?

Answer (score 3):

Смешались в кучу кони, люди...

`NULL`, приведенный к `float` — это просто нуль. `0.0f`.

При неверном аргументе, переполнении и т.п. исключения C++ **не** генерируются.

Если уж вы хотите исключений, то они должны перехватываться вместо `if(y==NULL)` — а так вы просто хотите превратить С++ в С.

Если уж вы хотите проверить, что вернулось — то проверяйте возвращенное значение с помощью функции [`isnan()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan) после возврата (а можно еще и `isinf()`, но лучше просто **[`isnormal()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnormal)**), а если хотите исключения — то проверяйте в самой функции и генерируйте исключение в случае, если возникли проблемы.

P.S. Загляните по поводу обработки математических ошибок [сюда](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/math_errhandling). Это, пожалуй, самый корректный вариант...

Comment: я посмотрел в отладчике, исключения генерируются при неверном x

Comment: и нужно, чтобы программа выводила в файл так же и недопустимые аргументы со значением nan

Comment: Да? И какое же конкретно **исключение С++** генерируется? :) И как, вы попадаете при этом в перехватчик `catch`? Тогда в чем же проблема, если все происходит, *как вы описываете*? Чтобы выводила NaN - просто выводите, будет запись типа `nan`, в чем тогда вообще проблема?

Comment: @pavel Скриншот из отладчика покажите. Скорее всего, перепутали исключение с какой-то другой ошибкой.